# How to import a chart in Extjs 5 as an image in a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-chart

Im using ExtJS 5 charts. I want to import the chart as an image and add it to a PDF file on the server side. However I'm not able the chart as an image at all.
Please let me know how i can solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getImage](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.CartesianChart-method-getImage) method of the chart to get an Image object.

Comment: Tried this but getting a TypeError : rect is null.
Cant figure out what this error is

Comment: Could you provide your test case jfiddle or sencha's fiddle?

Comment: Solved the issue. The error was due to rect not being defined.
Solved it by doing this :
Array.prototype.slice.call(chart.items.items)[0].setRect([100,100,200,200]);